# How do you get an SSL cert on a Beanstalk instance via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I'm using ELB with https passthrough as per the AWS example, as we need the SSL to be terminated at the Instance. I've got an existing .ebextensions YAML file that has the files key in it as per AWS's guide. This works well, until I want to use different certs for different environments.

My problem being I want to be able to upload different SSL certs via Cloudformation depending on which environment I'm deploying to. For example, test and dev get the test certificate, production get the production certificate.

I know how to use mappings, so that's not a problem, but I can't work out how to upload a file to an Elastic Beanstalk environment from Cloudformation.

I've tried adding the following code snippet in various places in the CloudFormation YAML, and it's not uploading the files. Is it something wrong in the code snippet, or am I missing something else? I tried adding the EC2::Instance section, but that creates a new EC2 instance outside Beanstalk, which I don't want.

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
    S3Auth:
      type: "s3"
      buckets: ["s3-bucket"]
      roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
  AWS::Cloudformation:Init:
    config:
      files:
        /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
          mode: "000400"
          owner: root
          group: root
          authentication: "S3Auth"
          source: !FindInMap [Certificates, crt-file, !Ref Environment]
        /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
          mode: "000400"
          owner: root
          group: root
          authentication: "S3Auth"
          source: !FindInMap [Certificates, key-file, !Ref Environment]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [normal file creation method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files) of Elastic Beanstalk. Create a file named `certs.conf` in a folder named `.ebextensions` and put this in it:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["s3-bucket"]
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

files:
  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: !FindInMap [Certificates, crt-file, !Ref Environment]
  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key":
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: !FindInMap [Certificates, key-file, !Ref Environment]
```

If `!FindInMap` doesn't work in that section, you can always have a little build script that puts the right certificates in place before calling `eb deploy`.

Comment: Awesome. In the end I passed in a variable for what environment it was and wrote a simple bash script with if env = x then copy y, else copy z. It's worked, but is less than elegant.